# Infinitely run Jython Weblogic Script

Tags: python, jython, wlst

The following script is an extract from

https://github.com/RittmanMead/obi-metrics-agent/blob/master/obi-metrics-agent.py

The script is written in jython & it hits the weblogic admin console to extract metrics
The problem is it runs only once and does not loop infinitely

Here's the script that I've extracted from the original for my purpose:

```
import calendar, time
import sys
import getopt

print '---------------------------------------'

# Check the arguments to this script are as expected.
# argv[0] is script name.
argLen = len(sys.argv)
if argLen -1 < 2:
    print "ERROR: got ", argLen -1, " args, must be at least two."
    print '$FMW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh obi-metrics-agent.py  <AdminUserName> <AdminPassword> [<AdminServer_t3_url>] [<Carbon|InfluxDB>] [<target host>] [<target port>] [targetDB influx db>'
    exit()

outputFormat='CSV'
url='t3://localhost:7001'
targetHost='localhost'
targetDB='obi'
targetPort='8086'

try:
    wls_user = sys.argv[1]
    wls_pw = sys.argv[2]
    url  = sys.argv[3]
    outputFormat=sys.argv[4]
    targetHost=sys.argv[5]
    targetPort=sys.argv[6]
    targetDB=sys.argv[7]
except:
    print ''

print wls_user, wls_pw,url, outputFormat,targetHost,targetPort,targetDB

now_epoch = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())*1000
if outputFormat=='InfluxDB':
    import httplib
    influx_msgs=''

connect(wls_user,wls_pw,url)
results = displayMetricTables('Oracle_BI*','dms_cProcessInfo')

while True:
    for table in results:
        tableName = table.get('Table')
        rows = table.get('Rows')
        rowCollection = rows.values()
        iter = rowCollection.iterator()
        while iter.hasNext():
            row = iter.next()
            rowType = row.getCompositeType()
            keys = rowType.keySet()
            keyIter = keys.iterator()
            inst_name= row.get('Name').replace(' ','-')
            try:
                server= row.get('Servername').replace(' ','-').replace('/','_')
            except:
                try:
                    server= row.get('ServerName').replace(' ','-').replace('/','_')
                except:
                    server='unknown'
            try:
                host= row.get('Host').replace(' ','-')
            except:
                host=''
            while keyIter.hasNext():
                columnName = keyIter.next()
                value = row.get(columnName )
                if columnName.find('.value')>0:
                    metric_name=columnName.replace('.value','')
                    if value is not None: 
                        if outputFormat=='InfluxDB':
                            influx_msg= ('%s,server=%s,host=%s,metric_group=%s,metric_instance=%s value=%s %s') % (metric_name,server,host,tableName,inst_name,  value,now_epoch*1000000)
                            influx_msgs+='\n%s' % influx_msg
                            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('%s:%s' % (targetHost,targetPort))
                            ## TODO pretty sure should be urlencoding this ...
                            a=conn.request("POST", ("/write?db=%s" % targetDB), influx_msg)
                            r=conn.getresponse()
                            if r.status != 204:
                                print 'Failed to send to InfluxDB! Error %s Reason %s' % (r.status,r.reason)
                                print influx_msg
                                #sys.exit(2)
                    else:
                        print 'Skipping None value %s,server=%s,host=%s,metric_group=%s,metric_instance=%s value=%s %s' % (metric_name,server,host,tableName,inst_name,  value,now_epoch*1000000)
```

I've tried to use the While loop, but that just stopped the code from exiting and not re-looping

What I want to achieve is to loop it infinitely post connection to weblogic
i.e. after this line

```
connect(wls_user,wls_pw,url)
```

and perhaps sleep for 5 seconds before re-running

Any and all help will be appreciated

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of condition for the loop :

```
mainLoop = 'true'
while mainLoop == 'true' :
```

and this for the pause between iterations :

```
java.lang.Thread.sleep(3 * 1000)
```